# New to Wordpress and my new web host has it by default so I am stuck

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently obtained a domain and website through bluehost. They have Wordpress installed and I am unable to figure out how to bypass it so I can code old school. I would really rather learn Wordpress but don't know where to start.

So two questions:

1.
what wordpress files are blocking me from the site recognizing the usual Default page's code? (I create test html in Default which is bypassed somehow and will only show Wordpress default page in progress; my code is not overwritten; just ignored?)

2.
I'd be happy to learn myself, but don't know a good resource. Went to Wordpress site and they have free webpage I can play with. Should I just get the free one in order to learn whats what...or is that going to be dumbed down and different than having it installed in webhost site?

I am a fairly advanced programmer and feel that I should be able to pick this up rather quickly if I can only get past this first hurdle.

Thank you for any information or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What loads by default at a domain (ex: www.yoursite.com) is controlled by the web server which uses a configurable list of filenames like index.html, index.php, Default.aspx etc. You can learn more about how that works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index).

Normally, your web host will allow you to have some control over that list, and the precedence one file takes over another when the web server refers to the list. Perhaps you have an administrative interface or dashboard control which allows you to configure this for your site. If not, you'll have to contact support at your web host to have changes made to that list.

1) Nothing is blocking you from seeing a page on your web server at a specific address, only from allowing one page or another to be what loads by default at the root web address, as explained above. If you have FTP access to your website directory, and can upload a file there, you can still browse directly to it, even though the WordPress installation's default page is showing up at your root web address. Just enter the specific file name in your browser, and you will browse to that page, ex: www.mysite.com/somepageicreated.html

2) Learning is always good either way, but you either want to learn to make WordPress sites or you want to learn to make your own websites. I'll assume WordPress for now, since you mentioned a preference for that platform. Just remember though: working with WordPress sites is not making your own website, it is changing a WordPress template to be as close as possible to what you want your website to be. This may or may not suit your requirements.

Playing with a free example from WordPress can be very useful for picking up the basics. Once you've played there for awhile and feel a bit more aware of how things work, take what you've learned and apply it to shaping your own site into what you'd like. Just remember to always create a backup of anything you mess with, so you can always return to an earlier state if you really mess things up good :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks; I actually just noticed that bluehost had a link to help with wordpress so I am set all around. Your answers are very useful and I get Exactly what you're saying. I've had webhosts before, but it's been a while and things have changed. I'm guessing it would be possible to have a combination of wordpress and my website by utilizing specific addresses and/or subdomains. Thanks Again!

Comment: One final addition that may help someone else in my predicament. I got to the 3rd walkthrough video from bluehost and I get it. Pretty much just another layer and software to learn and buy. Def in kahoots with bluehost and I understand. May utilize it for it's included resources and let it create pages that I'll alter and/or just leave it as my main page (linked from real main at domain\starthereinstead.html) for their market place and blog functionality. I can do that later and start on my page right away :))